Does potting soil deteriorate?
I have a 20 lb. bag of commercial potting soil in my garage that has been sitting there for years. The bag has been opened and a small amount removed, but otherwise it has sat there partially sealed for at least 5 years, maybe 10. It looks and feels perfectly normal like the day I bought it, but have changes occurred that would make it unsuitable for potting a new plant?

Many potting soil bags have small slits to allow some air exchange. Otherwise soil + moisture + dark = mold and decay agents
Chances are good the soil has dried out into clumps.  You can do your own check by opening the bag and checking for:

a musty smell indicate decay agents have been at work
big clumps indicates it has dried out
signs of mold or fungi and mushrooms indicates the organic matter is being eaten

If you see or smell any of these I would not use the soil for indoor plants but you could use it as topdressing for outside beds or lawns.  If it is lumpy you will have to wet it with hot water and a touch of dish soap as a surfactant to break up the clumps.
